# In Event Tracing for Windows (ETW), TraceEventSession don't catch read event from notepad

Tags: c#, windows, etw

I use hits filters:

```
session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.DiskFileIO |
                                             KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIOInit |
                                             KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIO);
```

I subscribe on `DiskIORead`  and `FileIORead` events.

If I open the file through notepad, then the event does not occur.

However, if I open the file through notepad ++, then this happens.

**UPD:**

Full Code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        using(var session=new TraceEventSession("Test"))
        {
            session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.DiskFileIO |
                                         KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIOInit |
                                         KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIO);


            session.Source.Kernel.FileIORead += Kernel_FileIORead;
            session.Source.Kernel.DiskIORead += Kernel_DiskIORead;
            session.Source.Process();
        }
    }

    private static void Kernel_FileIORead(Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers.Kernel.FileIOReadWriteTraceData obj)
    {
        if (obj.FileName.ToUpper().StartsWith(@"E"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2:" + obj.FileName);
        }
    }

    private static void Kernel_DiskIORead(Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Parsers.Kernel.DiskIOTraceData obj)
    {
        if (obj.FileName.ToUpper().StartsWith(@"E"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("2:"+obj.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

I use Windows 10.

Comment: @Clint E is disk letter. I make filter by Disk Letter.

Comment: Nevertheless, I saw event taking place when I created a notepad file, opened the file. Only that I have set the query to look for FileNames that start with `E`. I;m quiet sure that it will work with FileIO in C Drive also

Comment: @Clint U have Windows 10?

Comment: yes that is right

Comment: `are you saying that when you use notepad to open a file in E Drive Kernel_FileIORead does not trigger, but when you open with notepad++ Kernel_FileIORead triggers ?` Yes. Notepad++ Fire event

Comment: Yes,Kernel_FileIORead

Comment: `what about opening any other editors like word doc or excel , ideally it should fire` WordPad fire event

Comment: `t should fire for any FileIORead operations, irrespective of app (Notepad++) right ? ` Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207483/discussion-between-clint-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `Source` for  `FileIOQueryInfo` like this

`session.Source.Kernel.FileIOQueryInfo += Kernel_FileIOQuery;`

**Event Handler**

```
private static void Kernel_FileIOQuery(FileIOInfoTraceData obj)
{
    if (obj.FileName.ToUpper().StartsWith(@"E"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("queryInfo:" + obj.FileName);
    }
}
```

**Note:** Issue replicated by partitioning `E:\`

*Tested it by opening a txt file in `E:\`  via notepad, wordpad*.
 *Tested it by opening a word file in `E:\ drive` via MSWord*

**PS**

*If you want to filter by process then you can use* `obj.ProcessName == "notepad"`

**References**

Highly Recommend going through this *[doc](https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/blob/master/documentation/TraceEvent/TraceEventProgrammersGuide.md)* from GIT