How to monitor file access?
I want to monitor when some process reads a specific file
When I use procmon to monitor the said file I can see that it gets queried and read a lot

Now I want to monitor a specific file and act once the CloseFile operation was executed on said file.
So I've installed the Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent nuget package and tried numerous things to get this working. It seems to work randomly? But it hasn't worked in a while.
Couple of things to mention:

My IDE runs w/ admin privileges.
I've disabled procmon just to make sure it doesn't interfere..
I've made sure that the callback is executed (I can log tons of filenames here. but just not the one I'm looking for)
I've set the keywords to All because w/ FileIO keywords it never worked
I've checked the LostEvents number provided by the callback. But it never was not 0

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    using TraceEventSession session = new("MySession");
    session.EnableKernelProvider(KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.All);
    session.Source.Kernel.FileIOClose+= data =>
    {
        if (data.FileName == @"c:\foo.txt")
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    };
    session.Source.Process();
});


Huh, interesting. On a quick test, the callbacks fire if the file is created after monitoring has started. If the file already exists, I get nothing (unless it's deleted and re-created, then it starts firing off).

The names and purpose of events in ETW are very ambiguous. Try FileIOCreate instead of FileIOClose. Don't ask me why that is...

If you enable all events you are enabling some really hefty providers where you are most likely loosing quite a lot of events on the way. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60119460/in-event-tracing-for-windows-etw-traceeventsession-dont-catch-read-event-fro how you should enable KernelTraceEventParser.Keywords.FileIOInit and friends to enable the ones you actually need for this task.

One problem for a realtime provider is that you need to do some FileIO rundown to enumerate all already open files to get the file names for all already open files. That might explain why you are missing some file names. Not sure if TraceEvent has implemented that.
